# Windows Updates Fails Server 2008 0x80070490

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update

I have a server with Windows Server 2008 Standard x64 Edition installed.  This has been installed and running for several months and I have been able to successfully install previous Windows Updates. I have two pending updates that fail to install.

- (KB967723) Security update for Windows Server 2008 x64 Edition
- (KB976098) Update for Windows Server 2008 x64 Edition

[image]

Fails with Error code: 80070490

Followed [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958044) off Microsoft support site, which basically says to repair Windows with the install DVD.  When I get to the step to select upgrade I get the following error.

> Upgrade has been disabled. 
>        The upgrade cannot be started. To upgrade, cancel the installation and
>   then choose to upgrade to a version of
>   windows that is more recent then the
>   version you are currently running.

So basically feel like I've hit a dead end with out doing a complete reinstall. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I happened to be researching this same error code this morning, and came across this MSDN blog post that *might* help: [How to overcome error 0x80070490 when installing updates in Windows Vista/Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/andrekl/archive/2008/09/29/how-to-overcome-error-0x80070490-when-installing-updates-in-windows-vista-server-2008.aspx)

I **was not** able to get it working again by following his step-by-step, but the following **did**:

1. Open `%windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log`. You'll likely need to run Notepad as Administrator in order to view it.
2. Go to the bottom of the log and do a find for "Error", making sure you choose *up* for the direction
3. This should bring you to one or more errors like the following:

   > 2008-09-27 15:53:29, Error
   >   CBS    Failed to resolve Package:
   >   Package_for_KB905866~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.0.22.0.
   >   hr: 0x80070490
4. Do a web search for the KB number of the update that failed (*KB905866* in this case), which should bring you to a Microsoft page where you can download the stand-alone installer for this issue's patch
5. Download and install the appropriate version (32-bit, 64-bit, etc.)
6. The next time you run Windows Update, it will recognize that the update was installed.

Comment: Thanks berberich, there were two "Failed to resolve child of Package" errors, manually installed the updates, and all is good !

Comment: Same here-All fixed  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the [System Update Readiness Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) which fixed error 80070490 for me on my Dell Server.